# Event for jQuery slider handle onClick()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am trying to start playing music on my website once one clicks on the handle of a jQuery slider. Currently, I have the slide event determining when to start playing the music. The problem with this is that the user has to actually move the slider for the music to start, which skews the values I am recording from the slider.

Has anyone been able to get something similar to this to work? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan there's no code to share. the slider has a number of available events, none of which will indicate when the handle is clicked instead of dragged.

Comment: For reference, here's the documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: You could bind mousedown or click event to `.ui-slider-handle`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your slider is identified as **#slider** use the following snippet to assign a click event to the handle:

```
jQuery('#slider>span').on('click', function() {
     console.log('slider clicked'); // delete this test line
     // your start_playing_music() function
});
```

PS: I think you mean [jQueryUI Slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/).